# Could not find com.github.awslabs:aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-signature

I am using `com.github.awslabs:aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor:deb7941e85` for AWS Request signing as suggested in the [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/request-signing.html#request-signing-java)

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.awslabs:aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor:deb7941e85'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/' }
      ...
}
```

The build was working perfectly till September 15, 2021, but now I am getting the below exception

```
Could not find com.github.awslabs:aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor:deb7941e85
```

When I analyze I could see that the `aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor-deb7941e85.jar` is not available in the `mulesoft` repository's location `https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/github/awslabs/`

```
https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/github/awslabs/aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor/deb7941e85/aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor-deb7941e85.pom
https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/github/awslabs/aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor/deb7941e85/aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor-deb7941e85.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://jitpack.io:

It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Could you explain elaborately, How did you resolve the issue?

Comment: added a repo(mvn)<repository>
      <id>jitpack.io</id>
      <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
  </repository>